# constant too big C++

Tags: c++, constants

I am working with a src someone made for a game I am making. the person recently has left and I am trying to pick up the pieces, I don't really know c++ but I was hoping to get some help with a compile issue coming from a specific file I am trying to compile. is there a way I can stretch the limits of a const or perhaps use a different type that will hold much larger values?

Comment: Can we see actual code?

Answer (score 1):

The numeric limits for the fundamental types of your implementation are defined in the `<limits>` header, and the trait class [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) provides the values for your machine. That's the end of it, you cannot "beat" those limits with fundamental types. Example (from cppreference.com):

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "type\tlowest\thighest\n";
    std::cout << "int\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "float\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<float>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "double\t"
              << std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() << '\t'
              << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8440f783c50ffdc)

If you want more than this, or even arbitrary precision/length numbers, then you need to use a multi-precision library, e.g. [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).